# Upgraded Amazon EC2 Instance Type, how do I access increased storage?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 R2 x64 instance that I upgraded from "micro" to "large". I upgraded it by stopping it, then right clicking on the instance in the AWS Management Console and change the instance type. When I booted it up again, it still had only a 30GB HDD, and I could find no unallocated space in the Disk Manager.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 30GB you're seeing is the EBS-backed volume that was carried over from your t1.micro instance.

To gain access to the ephemeral disk that comes with the m1.large instance, you need to specify that when you start the instance:

```
$ ec2-run-instances ami-XXXXXX -k <key> -g <security_group> -b "xvda=ephemeral0" -t m1.large
```

Keep in mind that this really, truly is **ephemeral** storage. It will go away, so don't use it for anything other than temporary storage. For anything that matters, use EBS-backed volumes.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the EBS-backed volume?

Comment: You can snapshot it and launch a new volume with a larger size, then swap them out.